# Designing the UI for a Multitenant Application

Tags: multi-tenant, saas

We are developing a multitenant application with shared schema for a web application. I would like to know the best practices for designing UI strategies.

We will have different roles for saas owners like Adminsitrators, Helpdesk, Account Manager so The SAAS owner may need to have multiple users who will acess the application and do their job.

**HelpDesk:** If a tenant put up a ticket, helpdesk team shall be able to view and solve.

**Account management:** Account Managers may need to access the payment information of the tenants for following up the tenants.

**ServiceManagers:** To perform maintenance and upgrades etc.

In this case

Do we need to have different UI for "Saas owner" and "Tenants" or is it better to manage it with permissions and roles?

Any best practices?

Comment: you forgot to mention the operations that a "Saas owner" can do in your application

Comment: Hi @Saravanan. Saas Owner Roles will have following modules

1. Account Manager for Tenant Account Management
2. Helpdesk: For Tenant Support
3. Super Admin: For any actions related to super admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many facets to decide on the mode of delivery

1. In case you prefer to use `Micro FrontEnds`, admin and tenant functions can be separate. However, the individual functions like help desk,Accounts management can be a separate micro frontend
2. There should be options for a tenant to white label the UI (custom logo, custom theme, custom layout (more development effort)) etc.

With or without micro frontends, your UI layer should be working based on the permissions that comes as an aggregation of the user's roles (even across tenants).

The UI always has probes to the API to get the permissions and render the various UI components based on the granted permissions to the user.

We used to build custom UI components like custom grid, custom forms etc so that the permissions could be used to show or hide the various UI elements based on the permissions that a user might posses.

Ex: In the context of a Administrator, I will be able to see all the team members, but in the context of a `Service Administrator`, I will be able to assign members to various tenant functions like help desk, accounting etc which the `Administrator` will not be able to perform, but can view the mappings.

Similarly, your business requirements will drive the UI, hence if you follow using the `permissions` for the UI, it is always `very fine-grained` and easy to manage than depending upon higher levels of abstraction like `Roles`.

HTH

Comment: Hi Thank you for providing a detailed reply for my question. Regarding the Stack We are planning to use .Net Core as a backend with SQL Server as DB and Later we may think of Raven DB too. Front end will be Angular. It will be a microservice.

My Major Concern was about Managing the UI for Saas Owner /Admin and Tenants. We were thinking to go with a different UI for SAAS Owner with ability to have Tenant management (Account Mgmnt, Plan, Billing) and Helpdesk support for providing supports for tenants and a different App UI that each tenant will be used. Appreciate if you comment on this.

Comment: yes, in that case you can build a separate UI (Micro Front-end) for SaaS Owner and separate ones for the tenant's. The catch here is that you might have to share some of your components across these UI like a tenant might want to view his plan, his billing details like cycle, historical bills etc. however, all of these can be done like separate applications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, we are planning to do like that, to make it different UI for both.